# SQL Case Statement Issues

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to make what I believe to be two additional case statements to a SQL query and can’t figure out how to add these particular ones.

What I want is to improve the case statement for partner_name & publisher_name.  Right now if a user comes from an organic app store search, the partner_name & publisher_name are “ “.  I want to replace the “ “ to something usable for reading it so there are not rows with empty data.  What I want is to improve on the case statement already in the query for both above parameters to so that Internal & Organic are covered.  The goal would be these two fields when the channel is organic or internal would insert the channel name instead of being empty.

The data in the source table is always in UTC time, but we use PST time.  Have to keep it in UTC (long story).  All items are strings.

Here is an example of an output of this.

[Example Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRhhW.png)

Here is my current SQL

```html
select install_date, campaign_type, channel, campaign_name, platform, partner_name, publisher_name, count (idfa)
from
(
select  
DATE(DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(left(timestamp_iso,19)),-7, 'HOUR')) install_date,
case when last_attributed_touch_data_tilde_feature = '' then 'organic' else last_attributed_touch_data_tilde_feature end as  campaign_type,
case when last_attributed_touch_data_tilde_channel = '' then 'organic' else last_attributed_touch_data_tilde_channel end as channel,
case when last_attributed_touch_data_tilde_campaign = '' then 'organic' else last_attributed_touch_data_tilde_campaign end as campaign_name,
case when last_attributed_touch_data_tilde_advertising_partner_name = '' then last_attributed_touch_data_tilde_channel else last_attributed_touch_data_tilde_advertising_partner_name end as partner_name,
case when last_attributed_touch_data_tilde_secondary_publisher = '' then last_attributed_touch_data_tilde_channel else last_attributed_touch_data_tilde_secondary_publisher end as publisher_name,

last_attributed_touch_type,
case when lower(user_data_platform) like 'android%' then 'Android' when user_data_platform like 'IOS%' then 'iOS' else 'Other' end as platform,
user_data_aaid,
user_data_idfa,
user_data_idfv,

case when (user_data_aaid is null or user_data_aaid = '') and (user_data_idfa = '' or user_data_idfa is null ) then user_data_idfv
when (user_data_aaid is null or user_data_aaid = '') then user_data_idfa
else user_data_aaid end as idfa,


FROM table_date_range([app_install_date_], timestamp('2018-06-23'), timestamp('2018-06-25')) --Change timestamp as required
where 1=1
and DATE(DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(left(timestamp_iso,19)),-7, 'HOUR')) >= '2018-06-23'
and DATE(DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(left(timestamp_iso,19)),-7, 'HOUR')) <= '2018-06-24'
group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
  order by 1 desc, 2 desc, 6 desc
  )
  group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

I am just not sure how to modify or change my case when statement for advertisign_partner_name & secondary_publisher_name.  I tried doing it but it only works when the channel is internal... Not organic.  I want it to handle both internal and organic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The goal would be these two fields ... insert the channel name instead of being empty

Short cut is:
instead of

```
SELECT install_date, campaign_type, channel, campaign_name, platform, 
  partner_name, publisher_name, count (idfa)
```

use

```
SELECT install_date, campaign_type, channel, campaign_name, platform, 
  IF(partner_name = '', channel, partner_name) AS partner_name, 
  IF(publisher_name = '', channel, publisher_name) AS publisher_name,
  count (idfa)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you help me understand what SQL is doing here?   The if statement, it has , channel, partner_name in it.  What is SQL doing with channel, partner_name.  Does this mean it takes channel if it is not null and partner_name if channel is null?

Comment: it does exactly what it sounds if you just read - so - if value of partner_name is empty string - output value of channel otherwise output value of partner_name. hope this makes sense to you :o)